# composer does not add files to autoload

Tags: composer-php

In a composer project I have to add a library, which does not have a `composer.json` and does not use namespaces. Therefore I adapted my project's `composer.json` to add the library:

```
{
    [...]
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "interpid/tfpdf-table",
                "version": "5.1.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "contrib/tfpdf_table_5.1.0.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["", "classes/", "classes/Pdf/", "classes/Pdf/String/", "classes/Pdf/Table/Cell/", "font/"],
                    "files": ["tfpdf.php", "classes/pdftable.php"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        [...]
        "interpid/tfpdf-table": "5.1.*"
    }
    [...]
}
```

On `composer update` the zip file is extracted and stored in directory `vendor/interpid/tfpdf-table` as expected/configured. But the PHP files/classes are not added to the autoload files as defined by `classmap` or `files` configuration. `composer dump-autoload` does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out the zip is extracted to `vendor/interpid/tfpdf-table`, not `vendor/interpid`, which implies that extra root folder is part of the zip. Composer cannot magically guess that, it just resolves from the root package folder, so `vendor/interpid`. Therefore you have to prefix all your autoloader definitions with `tfpdf-table/`.

Run `composer update` with `-vvv` flag if you want to discover issues like this.

Comment: Your advice did not work out too. After some path changes and failed attempts I deleted the vendor directory and did a `composer update`. In my posted configuration everything was OK, the composer cache was the only problem and avoided an update of the autoload files.